# JSON value not returning, but displays on echo

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm working on a small program that extracts data from a table, and then builds an html table to display it in and returns that table back via JSON. What is happening though is that the table returns null. However at the end of the loop I can bring the table variable and it will display the table built perfectly in its entirety. I'm not receiving any errors and can't find an area where the table would reset itself. So if someone can help me out here that'd be amazing. My code is below, my apologies it's a little messy at the moment, I plan to clean it up soon:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
require_once '../../inc/config.php';
$response = array();
$response['table'] = "";
$table = "<thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Card Name</th>
            <th class='hidden-xs'>Card Number</th>
            <th class='hidden-xs'>Set</th>
            <th class='hidden-xs'>Rarity</th>
            <th class='hidden-xs text-center'>Market Avg.</th>
            <th class='hidden-xs text-center'>Change</th>
            <th class='hidden-xs text-center'>Sell Price</th>
            <th class='hidden-xs text-center'>Buy Price</th>
        </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>";
$cardname = $_REQUEST['card_name']; 

$set_id = $_REQUEST['set_name'];
$rarity = $_REQUEST['rarity'];
$where = "1=1";
$where .= !empty($cardname) ? " AND c.card_name LIKE :cardname" : "";
$where .= !empty($set_id) ? " AND c.setlist__id = :set_id" : "";
$where .= !empty($rarity) ? " AND c.ygo_rarity__id = :rarity" : "";
$q = "SELECT c.id, c.card_name, s.set_name, CONCAT_WS('-', s.set_abbr, c.card_number) as card_number, card_rarity, c.card_price, c.card_price_change, s.set_abbr, r.rarity_abbr FROM priceguide.cardlist c
    INNER JOIN priceguide.setlist s
    ON c.setlist__id = s.id
    INNER JOIN priceguide.ygo_rarity r
    ON c.card_rarity = r.rarity
    WHERE $where
    ORDER BY c.id ASC";

$stmt = $CONN->prepare($q);
$cardname = !empty($cardname) ? "%".$_REQUEST['card_name']."%" : "";
if(!empty($cardname)) $stmt->bindParam(":cardname", $cardname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
if(!empty($set_id)) $stmt->bindParam(":set_id", $set_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
if(!empty($rarity)) $stmt->bindParam(":rarity", $rarity, PDO::PARAM_INT);
if($stmt->execute()){
    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

        $table.="<tr>";
            $card = htmlentities($row['card_name']);
            $table.="<td><a href='' data-imageSrc='".$row['set_abbr']."/".$row['card_number']."-".$row['rarity_abbr'].".png' class='card-view' data-cardid='".$row['id']."'>".htmlentities($row['card_name'])."</a></td>";
            $table.="<td class='hidden-xs'>".$row['card_number']."</td>";
            $table.="<td class='hidden-xs'>".$row['set_name']."</td>";
            $table.="<td class='hidden-xs'>".$row['card_rarity']."</td>";
            $table.="<td class='hidden-xs text-center'>$".number_format(floatval($row['card_price']), 2, '.', '')."</td>";
            $change = number_format(floatval($row['card_price_change']), 2, '.', '');
            if($change == 0.00){
                $change = "<font color='#FFCC00'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-minus'></span></font>";
            }elseif($change < 0.00){
                $change = "<font color='#CC0000'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom'></span></font>\$$change";
            }else{
                $change = "<font color='#33CC00'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-top'></span></font>\$$change";
            }
            $table.="<td class='hidden-xs text-center'>$change</td>";
            $sell = number_format(floorToFraction(floatval($row['card_price']), 4), 2, '.', '');
            $maxprice = (($sell - 1.93)-($sell*.10))/1.35;
            $maxprice = floorToFraction($maxprice, 4);
            $maxprice = $maxprice < 0 ? number_format(0, 2, '.', '') : number_format($maxprice, 2, '.', '');
            $table.="<td class='hidden-xs text-center'>\$$sell</td>";
            $table.="<td class='hidden-xs text-center'>\$$maxprice</td>";
        $table.="</tr>";
    }
    $table .= "</tbody>";

    $response['errors'] = false;
    $response['table'] = $table;    
}else{
    $response['errors'] = true;
    $response['message'] = "There was an error when searching the database, plesae contact the system administrator";
}

echo json_encode($response);
function floorToFraction($number, $denominator = 1){
    if($number >  1.00){
    $x = $number * $denominator;
    $x = ceil($x);
    $x = $x / $denominator;
    return $x;
}else{
    return $number;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: is everything here UTF8 encoded? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076988/php-json-encode-json-decode-utf-8

Comment: I had just walked into that solution. so then a question would be, should I just utf-8 encode each line as it occurs, or would that be bad practice?

Comment: I have in the past just taken the entire big string I wanted to json-encode and converted it to UTF8 in one go. That worked for me.

Comment: cool if you want to put this as answer I'll check if it works, and if it does I'll accept.

Comment: Pleased to help, thanks for the tick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could well be because json_encode() in PHP requires that everything is UTF8 encoded. You could try

```
$response['table'] = utf8_encode($table);
```

I can't see anything else in there that might need encoding.