# JSON encode error for bengali fonts

Tags: php, mysql, json

Everything is working fine. But when I try to encode some Bengali font from mysql database problem occurred that time. Bengali fonts are displayed as "?????????????".

** Php file **

```
<?php 
define('HOST','localhost');
define('USER','xxxxxxx');
define('PASS','xxxxxxxx');
define('DB','xxxxxxxxx');

$con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);

$sql = "select * from bookinfo ORDER BY ID DESC";

$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$result = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
array_push($result,
array('id'=>$row[0],
    'name'=>$row[1],
    'writter'=>$row[2],
    'url'=>$row[3]
     ));
}

echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

[click here to see output result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujYXc.png)

Comment: You can get an idea by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076988/php-json-encode-json-decode-utf-8

Answer (score 12, accepted):

first set content type eg. header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8')

then set utf-8 code before execute your query

Like this:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');    
define('HOST','localhost');
define('USER','xxxxxxx');
define('PASS','xxxxxxxx');
define('DB','xxxxxxxxx');    
$con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);    
mysqli_query($con,"SET character_set_results = 'utf8', character_set_client = 'utf8', character_set_connection = 'utf8', character_set_database = 'utf8', character_set_server = 'utf8'");

$sql = "select * from bookinfo ORDER BY ID DESC";

$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$result = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($res)){
array_push($result,
array('id'=>$row[0],
'name'=>$row[1],
'writter'=>$row[2],
'url'=>$row[3]
));
}   
echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);    
mysqli_close($con);    
?>
```

It will give you correct font as you expected.

Answer (score 2):

```
 header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: Your table field should have UTF-8 as encoding

Comment: Actually i want to parse it to android app. so no need table here.

Comment: If you have Bangla text in ur database then you dont have to worry about it!! Ask android dev to encode it on device side!! the result in image is for ur understanding, its just  a temp output for you!