# Fix broken unicode escape without leading slash in PHP

Tags: php, json, unicode, utf-8

I have a JSON string from an ajax call which contains some special character. The problem is, that there is a function that removes all slashes from the string (which I have to use sadly). But it breaks any Unicode character in it...

**So I have a string like that:**

```
mmu00b2
```

**Which should be converted to UTF-8:**

```
mm²
```

I tried this regex here, but with no luck: `preg_replace("/u(\w+)/i", "\x$1", $str );`

Answer (score 1):

'/u(\w+)/i' will match 'u00b2' since \w+ matches with any word characters including underscores.

You should use '\d+' instead to only matches the digits. This will give you a match of 'u00' and breaks from 'b' so you won't need to add $1 anymore on your replacement.

```
preg_replace("/u(\d+)/i", "\x", 'mmu00b2')
```

output: mm/xb2

Comment: Thank you for your help, however, this doesn't quite do what it should... So ended up by fixing the escaped Unicode by adding the slash `preg_replace('/u(\d.{3})/i', '/\1', $str)` to it back. Then you can just save it to the DB with `json_encode( $str, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE ).`  Also notice this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/30424859/7149996